# Javascript Event Handler to Fire C# Method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

A .NET application I've been working on is hanging on a certain function call. I wanted to know if there is a way that the event handler can "fire" the C# function instead of calling it and waiting for a return; in other words, I need it to continue running Javascript code instead of waiting. How would I achieve this functionality?

Here is a code outline:

**Javascript**

```
// Fires on user scroll event
function ScrollHandler() {
    //...
    // Calls the following C# function when a user scrolls
    window.external.UserScroll();
}

// Called by C# function UpLoadJson()
function drawTimeline(JsonData) { 
    //...
}
```

**C#**

```
// Called by Javascript function ScrollHandler()
void UserScroll()
{
    //...
    UpLoadJson();
}

void UpLoadJson()
{
    //...
    browser.Document.InvokeScript("drawTimeline", new String[] {data});
}
```

Using "`->`" to denote a function call, what I think is happening is:

`ScrollHandler(/*JS*/) -> UserScroll(/*C#*/) -> UpLoadJson(/*C#*/) -> drawTimeline(/*JS*/)`

But the Javascript can't run `drawTimeline()` because it is waiting for `ScrollHandler()` to return first; this can't return until `drawTimeline()` is called though. I need `ScrollHandler()` to return without waiting for a return from `UserScroll()`.

@fabjan Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.external.HandleScroll(left, right),
            type: "GET"
        })
        // seems like this part would be optional, since calling HandleScroll() will
        // result in the draw function if it needs to
        /*.done(function (jsondata) {
            drawTimeline(jsondata);
        })*/
        .fail(function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to useJQuery Ajax get/post request and callback methods:

```
$.ajax({
    url: (your controller/actionname),
    type: "GET",
}).done(function (jsondata) {
    some code here...
}).fail(function (err) {
    alert(err.statusText);
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. The application still bites its own tail with this call.

Comment: What if you'll execute UpLoadJson method in different thread instead of using ajax? Try adding this line to UserScroll method - Task.Factory.StartNew(UpLoadJson).Start();

Comment: Visual Studio isn't at all happy about that line of code. How do I pass parameters for `UpLoadJson` with this `StartNew()` function?

Comment: Javascript code is running in single thread and when you call method  on server side synchronously it blocks the thread. You have two options : 1. Get quick response from server without json result and make another call later to get this result when it is ready.   2. use ajax and load result asynchronously

Comment: I think you just helped me figure it out. I could return the Json in the UserScroll method